# Getting MS VB Compilation Error "Object doesn't support this property or method: ObjNamespace.GetDefaultFolder"

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, hp-uft

My Problem Statement goes like this:
I want to trigger an Automated Email through Outlook to a User. Once the mail is triggered, script will wait for 2 minutes. If there is no Reply from the Recipient. I need to send a Reminder Auto- Mail to the same User.
Here is my VB Code :

```
Option Explicit 'Option Explicit forces variable declaration
Dim StartTime
Dim Elapsed
Dim Subject, Subject1
Dim Body
Dim sAttachment1
Dim oMailobj, oSendmail
Dim objOutlook
Dim objNamespace, objfolder
Dim fold,getsubfolders
Dim Inbox


Subject= "Test Run Results"
Body = "<Html><Body><h3><font face = " & "Callibri" & ">"  & "Hi," & "<br></br><br></br>" & "This is an automated Email for Test Run Results" & "<br></br>" & "<br></br>" &"Domain: Test"& "<br></br>" &"Project: Automation" & "<br></br><br></br>" &"Thanks,"&  "<br></br>" &"Testing Team"  &  "<br></br>" & "</font></h3>" & "<H5  align =" & "center" & ">" &"<font color = " & "Gray" & ">" & "This is an auto generated e-mail." & "</font></H5></Body></HTML>"
Sendemail "abc@xyz.com",Subject,Body,sAttachment1

StartTime = Timer 'Start the Timer
Wscript.Echo Time 'Print the current time



Elapsed = Timer - StartTime 'Initialize Elapsed variable (not critical)
Wscript.Echo Elapsed

Do While Elapsed < 60  

    WScript.Sleep(60000)  'Pause for 1 minute
    Elapsed = Timer - StartTime
    WScript.Echo (Elapsed)

Loop

Wscript.Echo "Hi"
Subject1 = "RE: " & Subject
Body = "<Html><Body><h3><font face = " & "Callibri" & ">"  & "Hi," & "<br></br><br></br>" & "This is a Reminder Mail for Test Run Results" & "<br></br>" & "<br></br>" &"Domain: Test"& "<br></br>" &"Project: Automation" & "<br></br><br></br>" &"Thanks,"&  "<br></br>" &"Testing Team"  &  "<br></br>" & "</font></h3>" & "<H5  align =" & "center" & ">" &"<font color = " & "Gray" & ">" & "This is an auto generated e-mail." & "</font></H5></Body></HTML>"

ReadInbox Inbox

'Function to send Email 
Function Sendemail (sMailto,sSubject,sBody,sAttachment)
    set oMailobj=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    set oSendmail=oMailobj.CreateItem(0)
        oSendmail.To=sMailto
        oSendmail.Subject=sSubject
        oSendmail.BodyFormat = 1
        oSendmail.HTMLBody=sBody

        oSendmail.Send
    set oSendmail=Nothing
    set oMailobj=Nothing
End Function

Function ReadInbox(foldername)
    'Dim objOutlook as Object
    Set objOutlook  = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objfolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'Inbox
    Wscript.Echo objfolder.Name

    Set colItems = objfolder.Items
    For each mail in colItems
        If mail.subject = "RE: " & Subject then
            Wscript.Echo "User has already replied within Time Limit"
            Exit For
        Else
            Sendemail "abc@xyz.com",Subject1,Body,sAttachment1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
    'msgbox colFilteredItems(1).subject
End Function
```

I am getting an Error Message at Line Number 59:
Set objfolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(foldername)

Attached the Error Screenshot as well.I run the same code in UFT as well. But getting the same error there as well.

[image]

Comment: Appears the question was answered. Consider rolling back your edit so the answer is not invalidated. You can ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").folders
```

It should be just:

```
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Comment: I made the change in the script. My concern is if i run it using the code via unread mail 
'Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
 'msgbox colFilteredItems(1).subject
Its working fine but rather i want to use the below code :-
Set colItems = objfolder.Items
 For each mail in colItems
  If mail.subject = "RE: " & Subject then
   Wscript.Echo "User has already replied within Time Limit"
  Else
   Sendemail "raman.kumar@capita.co.uk",Subject1,Body,sAttachment1
  End If
 Next
Here I am not getting the expected subject in mail.subject while seeing it through Watch

Comment: I got the Answer to my above comment, So code for latest mail in mailbox has to be like this 

Set colItems = objfolder.Items 
         If colItems.GetLast.subject = "RE: " & Subject then
            msgbox "User has already replied within Time Limit"
            
        Else
        'msgbox "test"
            Sendemail "abc@xyz.com",Subject1,Body,sAttachment1
            'Exit For
        End If
   ' Next
    msgbox "done